# Why are these CAShapeLayers not going where expected?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, cashapelayer

I'm working on a custom loading indicator and am having a lot of issues with CAShapeLayers.

The loading indicator will be contained within a custom UIView so that any viewController can use it.

First issue:

The frame of the subview is not matching the bounds.

When using this code to display a circle in each corner of the frame the circles are placed in a square shape but it is no where near the view.
    import UIKit

View Controller:

```
class MergingCicles: UIViewController, HolderViewDelegate {
func animateLabel() {

}

var holderView = HolderView(frame: CGRect.zero)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    addHolderView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func addHolderView() {
    let boxSize: CGFloat = 100.0
    holderView.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.width / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                              y: view.bounds.height / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                              width: boxSize,
                              height: boxSize)
    holderView.parentFrame = view.frame
    holderView.delegate = self
    holderView.center = self.view.center
    view.addSubview(holderView)
    holderView.addCircleLayer()
}
}
```

Subview:

```
Import UIKit

protocol HolderViewDelegate:class {
func animateLabel()
}

class HolderView: UIView {
let initalLayer = InitialLayer()
let triangleLayer = TriangleLayer()
let redRectangleLayer = RectangleLayer()
let blueRectangleLayer = RectangleLayer()
let arcLayer = ArcLayer()

var parentFrame :CGRect = CGRect.zero
weak var delegate:HolderViewDelegate?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)!
}

func addCircleLayer() {
    var circleLocations = [CGPoint]()
    let offset = CircleLayer().maxSize / 2
    circleLocations.append(CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - offset, y: self.frame.maxY - offset))
    circleLocations.append(CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX + offset, y: self.frame.minY + offset))
    circleLocations.append(CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - offset, y: self.frame.minY + offset))
    circleLocations.append(CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX + offset, y: self.frame.maxY - offset))
    circleLocations.append(layer.anchorPoint)
    for point in circleLocations {
        let circle = CircleLayer()
        circle.updateLocation(Size: .medium, center: point)
            self.layer.addSublayer(circle)

    }
    self.backgroundColor = .blue
   // layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: (self.bounds.maxX + self.bounds.maxX)/2, y: (self.bounds.maxY + self.bounds.minY)/2)
    let rotationAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.45
    rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true
    //rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1000
    //rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
  //  layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
}

}
```

Circle Layer:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum ShapeSize {
    case medium
    case small
    case large
}
class CircleLayer: CAShapeLayer {
let animationDuration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3
let maxSize = CGFloat(50)
override init() {
    super.init()
    fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
}

func updateLocation(Size: ShapeSize, center: CGPoint){
    switch Size {
    case .medium:
        path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: center.x, y: center.y, width: maxSize/3, height: maxSize/3)).cgPath
    case .small:
        path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: center.x, y: center.y, width: (2*maxSize)/3, height: (2*maxSize)/3)).cgPath
    case .large:
        path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: center.x, y: center.y, width: maxSize, height: maxSize)).cgPath
    }
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Result:

[image: Result using frame]

This really shows that the frame is no where near the uiView.

If I change `addCircleLayer` to use bounds instead I get something much closer:

[image: Using bounds]

But still the circles are not in the corners (except the bottom right one, that one is correct). It appears there is some extra space on the left and top of the view that is not captured using self.bounds.

The ultimate goal is to also rotate the circles 360 degrees around the center but as shown by the circle in the upper left corner the layer anchor is not in the center of the view, I changed the anchor to be the center of the circles but then nothing appeared on screen at all.

Comment: Try calling addHolderView() in the viewdidlayoutsubviews instead of viewdidappear to make sure the bounds of your view are what you expect. Just keep in mind this method will be called multiple times so make sure you dont re-add the layers every time

Comment: Good idea but getting the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was then when drawing the circles I was using `UIBezierPath(ovalIn:CGRect, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat` which was using the x value for the left side of the circle. When I changed to `UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool)` the point was used for the center of the circle and made it all fit where expected when using self.bounds to calculate the points.

After that I no longer had to change the anchor point as it was in the correct location by default.

I didn't figure out why the frame is in a completely different spot but it is no longer impacting the project.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying things like

```
circleLocations.append(CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - offset, y: self.frame.maxY - offset))
```

But `self.frame` is where the view is located in its own superview. Thus, the shape layer ends up offset from the view by as much as the view is offset from its own superview. Wherever you say `frame` here, you mean `bounds`.